# Вывод значений переменной в несколько строк Qlabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть словарь в нем хранится `size, filename`. Также есть код

```
data = collections.defaultdict(list)
names = data[(size, filename)]
if len(names) > 1:
   self.label.setText("{filename} ({size} bytes) may be duplicated " "({0} files):".format(len(names), **locals()))
   for name in names:
       self.label_2.setText("{0}".format(name))
```

Почему в label_2 выводится только 1 строка текста когда через вызов

`print("{0}".format(name))`

Выводятся все строчки текста. Вопрос почему так происходит и как сделать так чтобы в `label_2` выводились все строчки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы на каждой итерации устанавливаете в `label_2` новое значение, затирая старое. Замените

```
for name in names:
   self.label_2.setText("{0}".format(name))
```

на

```
self.label_2.setText("\n".join(names))
```